# Use JSON Value with Tableau Desktop

Tags: tableau-api

I'm using Tableau Desktop to create dashboards. I linked a postgresql database to do that. In one of my column i have some JSON data, that looks like this:

```
{
"Head": {"count": 7, "cumul_time": 11.7425, "start_time": 1509372084.231364, "prev": 3.0, "bad_at": 4}, 
"Spine": {"count": 1, "cumul_time": 28.6284, "start_time": 1509372013.177559, "prev": 1.0, "bad_at": 4}, 
"WristRight": {"count": 1, "cumul_time": 0.0, "start_time": 1509371967.944035, "prev": 1.0, "bad_at": 1}, 
"ElbowLeft": {"count": 33, "cumul_time": 116.9077, "start_time": 1509372097.139932, "prev": 1.0, "bad_at": 2}, 
"ShoulderRight": {"count": 4, "cumul_time": 57.1627, "start_time": 1509372093.4216, "prev": 3.0, "bad_at": 4}, 
"WristLeft": {"count": 1, "cumul_time": 0.0, "start_time": 1509371967.944908, "prev": 1.0, "bad_at": 1}, 
"ElbowRight": {"count": 5, "cumul_time": 115.3749, "start_time": 1509371995.583759, "prev": 1.0, "bad_at": 2}, 
"ShoulderLeft": {"count": 2, "cumul_time": 15.1435, "start_time": 1509372090.531815, "prev": 2.0, "bad_at": 4}
}
```

So I want to, somehow, extract this to display which part of the body is used the most and display it.
I'm kinda lost I tried to use REGEX or to create a view but this is stored as a String in the database.

Comment: You have the tableau-public tag on your question. Tableau Public doesn't allow connections to databases. If you wish to use Tableau Public for this, Tableau Desktop has a JSON file connector built in.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, In fact i'm using Tableau Desktop (sorry for the confusion with tableau-public) and in one of my column i store a string, that is formated like JSON ( as shown above ) and i wondered if i could use this data directly to display which part of the body is used the most for example.

Comment: I realise this is an old question, but I am trying to do the same. Just started working on Tableau Desktop.    @AntoinePoussard did you find a way to do it?